# FutureBuilder widget not returnig the Pages I want - Flutter Firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, widget

When I try to use the FutureBuilder Widget to await a boolean value from my Firebase Database, it is not returning the values I want.

The return LoginPage() it's working fine.

Both print1 and print2 are being executed.6

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: Auth().authStateChanges,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return FutureBuilder(
              future: _getCurrentUserData(),
              builder: ((context, AsyncSnapshot<bool> hasAccountSetup) {
                if (hasAccountSetup.data == true) {
                  print("print1");
                  return MyHomePage();
                } else {
                  print("print2");
                  return AccountSetup();
                }
              }));
        } else {
          return LoginPage();
        }
      },
    );
  }

  Future<bool> _getCurrentUserData() async {
    final DocumentSnapshot userDoc = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Users')
        .doc(Auth().currentUser!.uid)
        .get();

    return userDoc.get('HasSetupAccount');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If HasSetupAccount is a field from your firestore database then try this:

```
 Future<bool> _getCurrentUserData() async {
    final DocumentSnapshot userDoc = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Users')
        .doc(Auth().currentUser!.uid)
        .get();
        Map<String, dynamic> data = docSnapshot.data()!;
    //HasSetupAccount should be the name of the field you want to access
    return data['HasSetupAccount']; 
}
```

Comment: The value is working fine, if I print it inside the futureBuilder is prints the right value

Comment: can you show how your firestore database looks? And to make it clear the error is that when you expect to receive a false it returns true and when you expect a true value it returns false?

Comment: but either value, true or false, it should return a new page, and it is not

Comment: Maybe your security rules don't allow you to go to that page. You can also try `Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute( builder: (context) => MyHomePage(),) );`
to change between pages

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).